# Is it possible to use OPENROWSET to import fixed width UTF8 encoded files?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, encoding, openrowset

I have an example data file with following contents and saved with UTF8 encoding.

```
oab~opqr
öab~öpqr
öab~öpqr
```

The format of this file is fixed width with columns 1 to 3 each being allocated 1 character and column 4 reserved 5 characters.

I have created an XML format file as below

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>  
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
   <RECORD>  
      <FIELD xsi:type="CharFixed" ID="Col1" LENGTH="1"/>       
      <FIELD xsi:type="CharFixed" ID="Col2" LENGTH="1"/> 
      <FIELD xsi:type="CharFixed" ID="Col3" LENGTH="1"/> 
      <FIELD xsi:type="CharFixed" ID="Col4" LENGTH="5"/> 
      <FIELD xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="LINE_BREAK" TERMINATOR="\n"/> 
   </RECORD>  
   <ROW>  
      <COLUMN SOURCE="Col1" NAME="Col1" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>  
      <COLUMN SOURCE="Col2" NAME="Col2" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/> 
      <COLUMN SOURCE="Col3" NAME="Col3" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>  
      <COLUMN SOURCE="Col4" NAME="Col4" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/> 
   </ROW>  
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Disappointingly running the following SQL...

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET
(
BULK 'mydata.txt',
FORMATFILE = 'myformat_file.xml',
CODEPAGE = '65001'
) AS X
```

Produces the following results

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
---- ---- ---- -----
o    a    b    ~opqr
�    �    a    b~öp
�    �    a    b~öp
```

from which I conclude the `LENGTH` is counting bytes rather than characters.

Is there any way I can get this working correctly for fixed *character* widths with UTF8 encoding?

(Target environment is Azure SQL Database reading from Blob storage)

NB: It was suggested in the comments that adding `COLLATION="LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8"` to the `FIELD` elements might help but the results remain unchanged with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> from which I conclude the `LENGTH` is counting bytes rather than characters.

This is correct and there is no way to make it characters instead.

The situation is analogous to the *n* in char(*n*), varchar(*n*), nchar(*n*), and nvarchar(*n*), where 'n' denotes the number of **bytes**, not characters. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql#remarks):

> A common misconception is to think that CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n), the n defines the number of characters. But in CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n) the n defines the string length in bytes (0-8,000). n never defines numbers of characters that can be stored. This is similar to the definition of NCHAR(n) and NVARCHAR(n). The misconception happens because when using single-byte encoding, the storage size of CHAR and VARCHAR is n bytes and the number of characters is also n. However, for multi-byte encoding such as UTF-8, higher Unicode ranges (128-1,114,111) result in one character using two or more bytes.

This is a source of confusion for many, especially since the [introduction](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928) of UTF-8 support. It was possible before with n(var)char and supplementary characters, but relatively rarely encountered I would say.

It would be nice if SQL Server extended its support for *characters* rather than *bytes* in several areas in future (including OPENROWSET).

In the meantime, [your workaround](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/303341) is the one I would probably use too.

Answer (score 9):

One workaround is to just change the format file to bring the whole line in, in bulk, and do the substring-ing in TSQL

With format file

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>  
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
   <RECORD>  
      <FIELD xsi:type="CharTerm" ID="WholeLine" TERMINATOR="\n"/> 
   </RECORD>  
   <ROW>  
      <COLUMN SOURCE="WholeLine" NAME="WholeLine" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/> 
   </ROW>  
</BCPFORMAT>
```

The following does return the desired results

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(WholeLine, 1,1) AS Col1,
       SUBSTRING(WholeLine, 2,1) AS Col2,
       SUBSTRING(WholeLine, 3,1) AS Col3,
       SUBSTRING(WholeLine, 4,5) AS Col4
FROM OPENROWSET
(
BULK 'mydata.txt',
FORMATFILE = 'myformat_file.xml',
CODEPAGE = '65001'
) AS X
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to put this out there as another option, especially for those who cannot modify the process within SQL Server:

You can also convert the file encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-16 LE (Little Endian; often referred to as simply "Unicode" within many Microsoft products). You would then change the following (from what is posted in the question):

**In the format file:**

1. Change `xsi:type` from `CharFixed` to `NCharFixed`
2. Double the value for each `LENGTH` (e.x. 2 -> 4, 5 -> 10)
3. For `<FIELD ID="LINE_BREAK" ...>`:

   1. Change `xsi:type` from `CharTerm` to `NCharFixed`
   2. Remove `TERMINATOR="\r\n`
   3. Add `LENGTH="4"` (use "4" for "\r\n" or 2 for "\n")

**In the call to OPENROWSET():**

1. Remove `, CODEPAGE = '65001'` as code page is ignored when using the "NChar*" `xsi:type`s.

**NOTES**

1. Needing to double the `LENGTH` value is even more (and sadder) evidence that `LENGTH` is always bytes. Sad that they didn't make it code units so that a `LENGTH` of "1" would get any BMP character, just like you would expect from `NCHAR(1)` / `NVARCHAR(1)` within T-SQL.
2. Why switch `CharTerm` to `NCharFixed` instead of `NCharTerm`? Because I couldn't get `NCharTerm` to work. My test data was 100% correct, yet using `NCharTerm` would only ever import the first row. Might be a bug.
3. While this does handle characters that in UTF-8 are either 2 or 3 bytes, neither this option nor UTF-8 handle combining characters. Meaning, the `ö` in the sample data can either be a single character (as it is in the sample data in the question), or it can be a combination of an unaccented `o` plus the diacritic mark (2 characters but now 3 bytes in UTF-8 as the diacritic is 2 bytes by itself, or 4 bytes in UTF-16). For example, I created the new character using:

   ```sql
   SELECT N'o'+NCHAR(0x0308); -- ö
   ```

   and then copy/pasted line 3 to a new line 4, swapping out the first character with what I just created, and changing the "ab" into "cd", just to be able to clearly distinguish the input rows. Doing this resulted in the following error:

   > Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line XXXXX
   > Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.

   I would expect the UTF-8 file to produce the same error given the same character.

   And to be fair, this scenario would also break the approach of pulling each line in entirely and using `SUBSTRING` to break it up, if not by producing an error, then at least by corrupting the data as `SUBSTRING` will still see `o` and `̈`  as two separate characters (since they are).